# Deleting an Item from a ListView using a context menu in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom list view in my application and in that some items has been added dynamically.Now I want to delete the items using the context menu and asking the user to select the delete option.I'm unable to achieve this please help me in solving this.
here is my code

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    db=this.openOrCreateDatabase("Hangman",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    c=db.rawQuery("select name from users", null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String usr=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            array.add(usr);
        }while(c.moveToNext());
 }
ArrayAdapter<String> adptr= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.member_name,array);
lv.setAdapter(adptr);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        val=lv.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), val, 5000).show();
    }
});


    adptr.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)  
{  
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");    
        menu.add(1,1,0, "Delete");//groupId, itemId, order, title   
}   
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();


}
```

Comment: `info.position` gives you the position of the list item that generated the context menu.

Comment: possible duplicate [Deleting items from ListView with a contextmenu in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795507/deleting-items-from-listview-with-a-contextmenu-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create an xml for menu for the delete and cancel.
2. registerForContextMenu(your-listview) in onCreate
3. onCreateContextMenu inflate the menu xml
4. onContextItemSelected implement this one and use this one to get item `AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();`
5. then check for R.id.delete case inside onContextItemSelected and  if true then remove data using info.position as index of the list.

hope it helps