# Android - Delete object in ListView with ContextMenu

Tags: android, listview, object, contextmenu, indexoutofboundsexception

first I apologise if I made any language mistakes because I'm not English.

EDIT : Resolved.

I'm trying to code a simple weather application. There is a list of cities and when you press on one of them you got more informations about temperature, etc.
I got a City class where all the infos are.
The ListView is working well, and when I choose a city the infos are correct.

For the next step, I would like to delete a city from the list with a ContextMenu.

I can make the ContextMenu appears when a long click happens, but I can't delete an item because when I press the delete button my code isn't correct : `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0` and so the app force close.

Here is my code :

```
package com.example.sauce.meteojojo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    //Liste des villes
    private final List<City> ville = new ArrayList<City>();
    Calendar Maintenant = Calendar.getInstance();
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private int position;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Création de la listwiew liée à son ID
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        //Liste des villes
        final List<City> ville = new ArrayList<City>();

//Creation des villes manuellement avec les informations decrites dans l'objet city
        City Paris = new City("Paris", "France", Maintenant, 12, "Sud", 1024, 30);
        City NewYork = new City("New York", "USA", Maintenant, 11, "Nord", 1023, 20);
        City Tokyo = new City("Tokyo", "Japon", Maintenant, 13, "Est", 1022, 15);
        City Rome = new City("Rome", "Italie", Maintenant, 10, "Ouest", 1021, 28);
        City LosAngeles = new City("Los Angeles", "USA", Maintenant, 14, "Sud", 1020, 19);
        City Moscou = new City("Moscou", "Russie", Maintenant, 15, "Nord", 1019, 12);

//Ajout des nom et pays sur l'arraylist, tostring change en string pour la liste.
        ville.add(Paris);
        ville.add(NewYork);
        ville.add(Tokyo);
        ville.add(Rome);
        ville.add(LosAngeles);
        ville.add(Moscou);

//Creation de l'arrayadapter permettant d'adapter l'arraylist pour la listview
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ville);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            //gestion du clic simple
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent monIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,InfosVille.class);
                //envoi des différents arguments de la classe city
                monIntent.putExtra("no",ville.get(position).getNom());
                monIntent.putExtra("pa",ville.get(position).getPays());
                monIntent.putExtra("da",ville.get(position).getDate());
                monIntent.putExtra("vi",ville.get(position).getVitesse());
                monIntent.putExtra("ve",ville.get(position).getVent());
                monIntent.putExtra("pr",ville.get(position).getPression());
                monIntent.putExtra("te",ville.get(position).getTemp());
                startActivity(monIntent);
                //Test toast
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    //Récupération du petit menu Supprimer
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    //Apres appui sur supprimer
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.del:
                position = (int) info.id;
                ville.remove(position);
                this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

City.java (the object)

```
package com.example.sauce.meteojojo;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by sauce on 14/09/16.
 */
public class City {

    private String nom;
    private String pays;
    private Calendar date;
    private int vitesse;
    private String vent;
    private int pression;
    private int temp;

    public City(String nom, String pays, Calendar date, int vitesse, String vent, int pression, int temp) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.pays = pays;
        this.date = date;
        this.vitesse = vitesse;
        this.vent = vent;
        this.pression = pression;
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.nom+" ("+this.pays+")";
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public int getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(int temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public int getPression() {
        return pression;
    }

    public void setPression(int pression) {
        this.pression = pression;
    }

    public String getVent() {
        return vent;
    }

    public void setVent(String vent) {
        this.vent = vent;
    }

    public int getVitesse() {
        return vitesse;
    }

    public void setVitesse(int vitesse) {
        this.vitesse = vitesse;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        String date2 = date.getTime().toString();
        return date2;
    }

    public void setDate(Calendar date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getPays() {
        return pays;
    }

    public void setPays(String pays) {
        this.pays = pays;
    }

}
```

I think the problem is that I didn't find the right thing to delete..
Thanks you for reading my post !

Have a good day.

EDIT : Thanks to answers this problem is solved, but another appears at this line on function onContextItemSelected :

`this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

I resolved this error too, because the adapter was also defined in the onCreate function so the global one wasn't used. 
Thanks and have a good day !

Comment: please check this so ans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795507/deleting-items-from-listview-with-a-contextmenu-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you defined `final List<City> ville` twice (once in the main activity and once in the onCreate function). You add the cities to the local one in onCreate, that's why the global one is empty when you try to remove stuff from it.

Just remove the line `final List<City> ville = new ArrayList<City>();` in onCreate and your code should work.

Comment: Thanks for your tip it worked, I don't know why I didn't see it before ... I found an other bug on this line after : `this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` There was a nullPointerException. I got the same problem because I defined in the onCreate too, so the global `adapter wasn't used. Thanks a lot everything works now !